# Why flush cache is not working?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cache, full-page-cache, hosting

My issue is I have two duplicate websites one for dev purpose and one is my live site.

When I change for example the theme color and flush the cache, working perfectly, color is changing.

But when I do the same thing on my Live site nothing changes.
I tried all the commands:

```
php70 bin/magento setup:upgrade;
rm -rf generated/*;
rm -rf pub/static/*;
rm -rf var/cache/*;
rm -rf var/page_cache/*;
rm -rf var/composer_home/*;
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*;
rm -rf var/cron/*;

php70 bin/magento setup:di:compile;

php70 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy;

redis-cli flushall; 
php70 /opt/magemojo/bin/n98-magerun2.phar cache:flush; 
php70 bin/magento indexer:reindex;
php70  bin/magento cache:clean;
php70 bin/magento cache:flush;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Varnish to cache on your live site I have found that restarting varnish sometime does the trick for the stubborn cache

```
service varnish restart
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are running your store in Magemojo, they have this command to clean almost everything: CloudFront, PHP OpCache, Redis FPC cache, Redis Config Cache and Varnish (if applicable). CloudFront can take up to 15 minutes to clear on all the edge nodes. This command does not clear Redis Sessions (redis-session) or Memcache.

```
/usr/share/stratus/cli cache.all.clear
```

I recommend using my tool [Deployer MageMojo Recipe](https://github.com/rafaelstz/deployer-magemojo) to automate this process during the deployments or just to run it faster in your local machine and the tool runs it inside of your instance. Here you can find the [MageMojo Stratus CLI reference](https://magemojo.com/kb/stratus-best-practices/stratus-cli/) as well.